# Subscribe to nchan for new messages only

Tags: nginx, notifications, publish-subscribe

I am planning to use nchan for notification system where on page load client will subscribe to channel and then publisher will publish to user specific channels and notifications will be sent to client via SSE.

So the problem I am facing with this solution is that on first subscription to nchan it gets older messages as well which were published before subscribing to channel. Though I can use timestamp based message id to filter out older messages but that requires clock sync on both client and server which is hard to implement.

So if there is any configuration or workaround I can do to implement this please let me know, it'll be of great help.

Answer (score 5):

I should have looked into documentation more than I actually did :).

I just needed to set **nchan_subscriber_first_message** to newest for the subscriber location.

```
    nchan_redis_url "redis://localhost:6379/6";
    location = /sub {
            nchan_subscriber;
            nchan_channel_id  $arg_id;
            nchan_use_redis on;
            nchan_subscriber_first_message newest;
    }

    location = /pub {
            nchan_publisher;
            nchan_channel_id  $arg_id;
            nchan_use_redis on;
    }

    location = /pubsub {
            nchan_pubsub;
            nchan_channel_id  $arg_id;
            nchan_channel_group test;
            nchan_use_redis on;
            nchan_subscriber_first_message newest;
    }
```